# ComboBoxEdit SelectedIndex always -1

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, devexpress, selectedindex

When I set comboBoxEdit.selectedindex = some value, it never take this value. its value is always -1.  I have set it in Constructor or in Form_Load.

```
if (oPersclientEntrp.TypPrint == 1) {
  comboBoxEdit_Print.SelectedIndex = 0;
} else {
  comboBoxEdit_Print.SelectedIndex = 2;
}
```

I have heard that The SelectedValue, SelectedIndex, SelectedItem properties can't be set until the control is added to the form. After the control is added to the form, the selectedValue, -Index and -Item properties can be set.

but I bind the value on design mode [image: design mode].

Comment: are you using DevExpress Controls??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating your code to be this:

```
if (oPersclientEntrp.TypPrint == 1) { comboBoxEdit_Print.SelectedIndex = 0; }
else { comboBoxEdit_Print.SelectedIndex = 1; }
```

If you only have 2 items, your `SelectIndex` should be 1, not 2.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 Items and the index of `SelectedIndex` starts with `0` (Because it access' an internal array, which of course starts with 0). So you have to edit your code to use index `0` instead of 1 and index `1` inseatd of `2`.

Btw, this is a common behavior of the most `SelectedIndex` properties, i.e. of `TabControl`.